# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() appeared in background before ViewController loads

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

I have some viewController called (A, B, C) when I call A VC and then redirect to B VC when B VC appeared I'm calling `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` on `viewWillAppear()` but `SKStoreReviewController` loads before B VC appeared and when C Vc gets called, I'm dismissing C VC and i'm able to see SKStoreReviewController behind C VC and it's also get dismissed with C vc without any interaction, I have tried to call it in `ViewDidLoad()` but it's also still not working. I'm not sure what exactly is root cause that `SKStoreReviewController` appeared behind VC, It was working fine for Xcode 11 and all iOS versions but i'm facing this problem in Xcode 12 and all iOS versions and 14.0 as well.
I'm sharing a snap of `SKStoreReviewController` pop-up. please help me out I have tried everything but I'm not sure the main reason.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you use the navigation controller to show B and C or you present them modally?

Comment: Yes, I'm using navigation controller to show A, B, C.

Comment: 'controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen'
'navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen'

Comment: @iUrii can you help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, try to make delay e.g. DispatchQueue.main.async { SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()  }. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have also tried that already but still facing same issue.